# Method suggestions don't work for 'nltk.corpus.wordnet` (vscode)

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

When I write `nltk.corpus.wordnet.`, method suggestions don't show up and I can't see the signatures of the functions that I call, even though the code executes fine.

This happens both in notebook and in regular `.py` files.

---

```py
import nltk
nltk.corpus.wordnet
```

This code prints `<WordNetCorpusReader in '/home/user/nltk_data/corpora/wordnet.zip/wordnet/'>`

Is the module is stored in a .zip file that gets unzipped at runtime? Is that why it's invisible to the IDE?

---

I also can't find an api reference for this module. They have a reference for `nltk.corpus.READER.wordnet` but not for the one without `reader`. There's just no way for me to even know the names of the methods that are available.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a clutch...

Suggestions do work for `nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.WordNetCorpusReader`, which is the same class that's imported with `nltk.corpus.wordnet`. I only needed to initialize it, so I did this:

```py
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
import nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet as wn

reader = wn.WordNetCorpusReader(wordnet.root, wordnet._omw_reader)
```

Now reader works exactly like `nltk.corpus.wordnet` and has method suggestions